# Working Around Bugs on Mobile Browsers With Javascript

Tags: javascript, mobile

I'm recently getting into some more advanced web design, so I am working on an interactive site right now. I use `setInterval` to perform all functionalities involving animations on the front page, fading in/out transitions, etc. I use plain javascript because I don't like to use jQuery and try to avoid it as much as possible. It works fantastic on desktop web browsers, only very little bugs. Firefox and Chrome work fine. However there are some problems with the mobile browsers.

So far I have only tried Safari IOS8 on an iPad Mini and have strange problems where the `setInterval` seems to stop functioning. As I said before, I have multiple threads of `setInterval` running, one of them is running a movie and the other is running a simple banner fade in/out. Some are triggered on click events and so forth.

The movie is the problem. I use a counter variable called i2 as an iterator every frame of the interval. I check for certain positions this counter is at to trigger events, AKA new scenes in the short movie. At the end of the movie, I reset the i2 variable back to 0 so the movie restarts. In mobile Safari, this i2 variable will not reset at all. I am unsure why because I have an i variable in another loop that resets well.

Here is my code for the movie:

```
var i2 = 0;
var lastframe;
var scene = 0;
var texts = ['Gwiddle', 'Web', 'Hosting', 'Reliable', 'Safe', 'Simple', 'Fast', 'Educational'];
var vel = 2;
var temp2;
var counter;
function movie() {
    var temp;
    i2 += 1;
    if(i2 > 50 && scene == 0) {
        scene = 1;
        for(var n = 0;n<3;n++) {
            add('p', 'movie', 'null', 'title');
            get('title', 'class');
            current[n].style.left = '0%';
            current[n].style.opacity = 0;
            current[n].style.top = 60 + n * 75 + 'px';
            current[n].innerHTML = texts[n];
            current[n].style.transform = 'rotate(0deg)';
        }
    }
    /*LARGE HUNK OF CODE REMOVED IT's NOT RELEVANT HERE*/
    } else if(scene == 5) {
        if((i2 - lastframe - 1) % 40 == 0) {
            counter += 1;
            get('verylarge', 'id');
            current.innerHTML = texts[counter + 2];
            if(counter == 5) {
                scene = 6;
                lastframe = i2;
            }
        }
        if(temp2 < 1) {
            temp2 += 0.05;
            current.style.opacity = temp2;
        }
    } else if(scene == 6) {
        if(i2 - lastframe > 30) {
            get('verylarge', 'id');
            temp = current.style.opacity;
            current.style.opacity -= 0.02;
            if(current.style.opacity < 0) {
                get('movie', 'id');
                current.innerHTML = '';
                i2 = 0;
                lastframe = 0;
                scene = 0;
                vel = 2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I removed some code to make it less long. As you can see most of it is a simple if tree that checks which scene it's on. The important part is the last if tree. At the very end I set i2 to 0.

I'm not sure if my code has any relevance to the question, but has anyone else experienced Javascript interpretation troubles and inconsistencies on mobile browsers, and how have you fixed them?

EDIT NOTE: I call to the function from a different Javascript file, so even though setInterval is not shown here it's present!!

Comment: Ah, I managed to solve it. Mobile browsers must have trouble with the subtraction of floating point numbers when going from a number above zero to one below zero - because the opacity would not go below zero of the text on mobile.

Comment: Take a look at velocity JS, it should make your life easier but there is a learning curve. http://julian.com/research/velocity/